# Derivative of $e^x$ (i)

Tags: calculus, derivatives, exponential-function

This will be a very basic question, but it will help my thought process to have someone answer it.

$e$ can be defined as the number such that $$\frac{de^x}{dx}=e^x\;\;\;\;\;(1)$$

Taking $x=2$, this implies that $$\frac{de^2}{dx}=e^2\;\;\;\;\;(2)$$

The power rule gives us that $$\frac{de^2}{dx}=2e\;\;\;\;\;(3)$$

Therefore from $(2)$ and $(3)$ we get $$e^2=2e\;\;\;\;\;(4)$$

But a calculator tells me that $(4)$ is false. Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: The power rule states that $$\dfrac{d(x^n)}{dx} = nx^{n-1}$$ notice that the base is $x$ and you are differentiating with respect to $x$. However, in (3), you are trying to use the power rule for an exponential function: $$\dfrac{d(e^x)}{dx}$$ Note that the base is $e$, not $x$. You are differentiating with respect to $x$, not $e$ (which is a constant and differentiation by a constant is undefined). The power rule does not apply to exponential functions.

Comment: $e^2$ is a constant, so $\dfrac{de^2}{dx}=0$

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Equations (2) and (3) are false. $e^2$ is a constant, and the derivative of a constant is zero.

Remember that you evaluate the derivative *after* differentiating the function.  So when you say $\frac{de^x}{dx} =e^x$, you mean that the slope of the line tangent to $y=e^x$ at $x=2$ is $e^2$.  In Leibniz notation, the correct form of (2) is
$$
    \left.\frac{de^x}{dx}\right|_{x=2} = e^2
$$
The correct form of (3) is
$$
    \left.\frac{dx^2}{dx}\right|_{x=e} = 2e
$$
As you can see, these are different functions, differentiated and evaluated at different points, so there's no surprise the derivatives are different.

*Dilatory aside.* You say that (1) can be taken as the definition of $e$, and you are right, with the insertion of the word *positive*.  Equation (1) is also satisfied with $e$ replaced by $0$, and if $e$ is “defined” to be zero, then (2), (3), and (4) are also all satisfied.

Answer (score 4):

Your equation (2) is misleading. It should really be written as $$ \frac{d e^x}{d x}|_{x = 2} = e^x|_{x = 2}.$$
Evaluating $\frac{d e^x}{d x}$ at $x = 2$ is not the same as $\frac{d e^2}{d x}.$

Comment: I like that extra step you took of putting the evaluation bar by $e^x$ on the right-hand side.